# VBA Word Numbering starting at 1 for every paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Sub that sets a specific Style for every wdListOutlineNumbering. My Problem is that the Numbering is ascending and i want to start at 1 for every paragraph.

My code so far:

```
Sub SetNumberingStyle()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListOutlineNumbering Then
            para.Style = "List Number"
            ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(4).Name = ""
            para.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
            ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(4),
            ContinuePreviousList:= _
            False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
            wdWord10ListBehavior
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

This won`t reset the numbering to start at 1.
My question is what i have to change in the code.

Comment: You can find a good article on how Word's numbering should be set up [here](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) Although an old article it applies to all version of Word since 2007

Comment: Won't the code run very slow with so many `if statement`?

Comment: @KinSiang: No. It just makes the code harder to read (but the VBA runtime doesn't care about hard to read code)

Comment: Can you explain (in words) what are you expecting from the above code? Or, in other words, what do you need to accomplish...

Comment: @FunThomas, I see, i first see many `If` statement in a loop...

Comment: What i try to accomplish is to reset the numbering for every new paragraph to start at 1 again. Right now it is ascending from 1 to 1XX...

Comment: Instead of `...ContinuePreviousList:= False,...` set the value to `True`.
`...ContinuePreviousList:= True,...` . Then It should Work.

Comment: @Raky tried that, didn`t worked.

Comment: Read the article I linked to in my previous comment. Learn how to set numbering up correctly using the UI first, then you can move on to doing it in VBA. Learn how to crawl before you try to run.

Comment: I think you will have catch each Paragraph and then set its Paragraph Number. Mere initialisations will not cause para numbers to be set. Alternatively, your macro should include statement to `Select` text of Whole Document and then apply the Paragraph Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description you need to execute a two step process:

First, apply the List Number style to all paragraphs where it is required. You are going to have to work out how to do this as your description of your document is vague and confusing.

Second, find the paragraphs formatted with List Number and restart the numbering where applicable. I have assumed that where there is a continuous run of paragraphs in List Number style you want them to be consecutively numbered. (Your question seems to indicate that you want every List Number para to be numbered 1, which I find illogical)

```
Sub RestartNumbering()

    Dim listTemp As ListTemplate
    Set listTemp = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleListNumber).ListTemplate
   
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        With .Find
            .Format = True
            .Text = ""
            .Style = wdStyleListNumber
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If Not .Previous(wdParagraph).Style = .Style Then
                .ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel _
                    ListTemplate:=listTemp, _
                    ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
                    DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Of course. if you are using outline numbering that has been set up correctly then you won't need to do this.

Comment: Dear @Timothy Rylatt, 
your Code worked perfectly! Thats what i was looking for